# DBMS_OUTPUT does not output anything, why so? I have tried everything by this point to fix it

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I need to see information from my database, but DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE doesn't output anything in Dbms Output section.

I tried setting server output on, restarting developer, i didn't find any other suggestions for problem

begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello');
end;

If i could at least see this hello message outputting, i could output my actual code, but at this point I don't see hello even.

Comment: Did you write - set serveroutput on 
before executing the block ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your DBMS version? I just tested on

> Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 -- PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0

Your code works alright.